# CRM Dynamics trigger workflow before saving

Tags: workflow, crm, microsoft-dynamics

A little background:

I have 2 entities (Product and Case).  The product entity will hold all product records.  A section in the Case will have the ability to choose products and auto-populate all related fields that are located in the product record for that specific product.  For example, Product record has fields like hazardous, range, lot ect.  The same field appear on the Case record.  These fields should only be populated based on the product that was selected.

I was able to accomplish the above by creating a 1:N relationship and adding it to my Case form.  I then created a workflow to populate the related fields (hazardous, range, lot ect).  However, these fields only populate when the record is saved.  Is there a way to make it update the fields once the product is chosen?

I want to refrain form using any type of JavaScript.  If possible, I would like to strictly use workflows to accomplish this (if at all possible).

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you have a lookupfield on your Case form, to select a Product?

Comment: yes, that is correct.  after some more research, it seems like the only way to have it change in real time is using a plugin of some sort.  A workaround that I found was to create a quick view form on the Products entity that only shows the fields that I want populated.  I then added this quick view form in the Case entity.  Now when someone picks a product, the quick view form shows the correct fields below it as if its actually part of the form itself.

Answer (score 1):

Real time information in your case can be only accomplished by using `JavaScript.` Maps works too but they have a special behavior.

`Workflows` that fire when the record is created only execute after all core operations are done (Native logic, `Plug-in` logic...) and you can't fire workflows if the record is not created.

So using workflows is a good idea even if you can't see the information